# This page isn’t workingwww.edsfze.xyz is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

I've deployed a laravel project on hostgator current PHP version on my PC is 7.2 and so does on HostGator hosting.

After deploying project in public_html and then moving code from public folder of laravel to main site folder and then changing the index.php code where it is now pointing correct directory of bootstrap and vendor.
Moreover, in .env file username, database name, password is also double checked they are fine.

So, after everything is fine then why am I still getting this error.

**This page isn’t workingwww.edsfze.xyz is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500**

https://www.edsfze.xyz/magrabi/

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d44JJ.png)

This is the error log:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\json_encode() in /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php:162
Stack trace:

#### #0 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php(968): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper->getDumpHeader()

#### #1 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/CliDumper.php(568): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper->dumpLine(0, true)

#### #2 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/CliDumper.php(263): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper->endValue(Object(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Cursor))

#### #3 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php(815): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper->dumpString(Object(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Cursor), 'Use of undefine...', false, 0)

#### #4 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/Data.php(405 in /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php on line 162

Comment: A 500 error just means that an internal server error occurred. It can be anything in your application. You need to access the web servers error log to find the real error message. Without that, we have no clue what it could be.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\json_encode() in /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php:162
Stack trace:
#0 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php(968): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper->getDumpHeader()
#1 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/CliDumper.php(568): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper->dumpLine(0, true)

Comment: #2 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/CliDumper.php(263): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper->endValue(Object(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Cursor))
#3 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php(815): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper->dumpString(Object(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Cursor), 'Use of undefine...', false, 0)

Comment: #4 /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/Data.php(405 in /home/edsfzexyz/public_html/magrabi/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Dumper/HtmlDumper.php on line 162

Comment: this is the error log

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59745743/edit) to include the error messages instead of in comments. You should also include the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error Solved by HostGator my hosting provider when i escalate the issue.

The browser 500 error that you were experiencing was due to many of the PHP modules not loading.  When a suPHP directive is active in the .htaccess file of the document root or any of its parent folders, it will prevent the default .ini files for EasyApache4 versions of PHP from being loaded.  I have corrected this issue by commenting out the suPHP directive in the home directory .htaccess.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Which .htaccess did you modify? is it the very root  right above the public_html folder?

Comment: Yes this is the main .htaccess file